# ast.literal_eval error when importing a python dictionary from external file to main file

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error, abstract-syntax-tree

So far I've converted the dictionary to a series of lists and consulted the documentation and a handful of questions on SO. I am slightly confused because a dictionary is one of the allowable structures that `ast.literal_eval()` can handle.

external dictionary file contents:

```
reports={
dict(DatabaseReports1='reports/dr_d1?'),
dict(DatabaseReports2='reports/dr_d2?'),
dict(DatabaseReports3='reports/dr_d3?'),
dict(TitleReports='reports/tr?'),
dict(BookReport1='reports/tr_b1?'),
dict(BookReport2='reports/tr_b2?'),
dict(BookReport3='reports/tr_b3?'),
dict(JournalReport1='reports/tr_j1?'),
dict(JournalReport2='reports/tr_j2?'),
}
```

main file contents :

```
with open('dictionaryFile.py', 'r') as f2:
        rs = f2.read()
        report=ast.literal_eval(rs)
```

I expect to convert the file from a string into a dictionary using `ast`, but I getting the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainFile.py", line 4, in <module>
   __import__("reportOptions")
  File "dictionaryFile.py", line 11, in <module>
    dict(JournalReport2='reports/tr_j2?'),
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a `set` of `dict`, which is why you get an error. Define a `dict` like this instead.

Moreover, when using `ast.literal_eval()`, you cannot make assignations, so get rid of the `report=`.

```
{
    'DatabaseReports': 'reports/dr_d1?',
    'DatabaseReports2': 'reports/dr_d2?',
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need to get rid of the `reports=` as well.